# Do we know enough to become fluent in written Mayan?

Tags: writing-systems, undeciphered-writing

There are [about **7000** languages](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/content/how-many-languages-are-there-world) but [**only three**](https://sites.utexas.edu/dsb/tokens/the-evolution-of-writing/#:%7E:text=Writing%20may%20have%20been%20invented,Near%20East%2C%20China%20and%20Mesoamerica.) origins of writing: The Middle East, China, and Mesoamerica. The most studied writing system in Mesoamerica is [Mayan script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_script). It was once the official language of a powerful empire, but then came the perfect storm: The horrific genocide of "colonialism" and [burning of texts](https://www.archaeology.org/issues/44-1211/features/maya-2012/305-groiler-dresden-codex#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mid%2Dsixteenth%20century,Dresden%2C%20Paris%2C%20and%20Madrid.), the warm and humid environment accelerating rot, and (like most societies of the time) only a small number of "elite" being literate in the first place.

Given these limitations, has enough of the language survived to learn fluency in reading and writing?

Answer (score 8):

There are two separate questions in one here.

First, Mayan hieroglyphs* are well-understood as a writing system. We have a solid understanding of the syllabic glyphs, with only a handful missing or not understood (e.g. we're not certain of a glyph for `/so/` or `/ʃe/`), and with those it's possible to spell out any word in the language. Similarly, we have a pretty good understanding of the common logograms that appear in the surviving texts; there may have been other logograms that didn't survive, but it's possible to do without these. *Breaking the Maya Code* claims 90% of texts can be read accurately as of the time of publication (2008). And indeed, people are trying to get the system encoded in Unicode, which…*normally* means it's well-enough-understood for people to actually use it. (But they also encoded the Phaistos disk symbols, so your mileage may vary there.) [You can find a good overview here.](https://www.wayeb.org/resources-links/wayeb-resources/workshop-handbook/)

However, *fluency* is a word usually used for proficiency with a *language*, not a *script*. And our understanding of the Classical Mayan language is limited—as you might expect, given the limited number of texts. If a particular word didn't appear in the surviving texts, there's no way to know it for sure. We can make a good guess, based on the dozens of related languages that are still living, but there are some things that can never be known for certain about a dead language.

Tl;dr **yes** the writing system is well enough understood to actually use it to encode new, original texts. However, there are limits to how much we can know about the Classical Mayan language, and gaps generally have to be filled in or extrapolated based on living relatives.

* I'm not sure if this is still the standard name for the system, since I've seen a half dozen different names in use, but it seems unambiguous enough to avoid any confusion.

Comment: they've also encoded linear A where there isn't even complete agreement on which symbols are distinct rather than simply variants of each other

Comment: @Tristan Yes, I must admit I am rather perplexed by many of the decisions made by the Unicode consortium. It seems entirely counter to their ostensible principles to encode glyphs when we don't even know if they encode language or not—and meanwhile the cuneiform encoding is a mess that really needs a good review. We might as well start encoding petroglyphs at this point.